# Flutter: A RenderFlex overflowed by 13 pixels on the bottom

Tags: android, flutter, render

When i tap on textfield i am getting this error

```
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 13 pixels on the bottom.
```

Below code is of the screen which is in bottom bar. I tried to wrapped the `Row` on `Expanded` widget but still same issue.

here is my code of BottomBar Navigation File

```
class BottonBarNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  final int? selectedIndex;
  const BottonBarNavigation({Key? key, this.selectedIndex = 1}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottonBarNavigation> createState() => _BottonBarNavigationState();
}

class _BottonBarNavigationState extends State<BottonBarNavigation> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  List<Widget> pages = <Widget>[
    HomeScreen(),
    BottomBarGroupsScreen(),
    BottomBarBylstScreen(),
    BottomBarProfileScreen(),

    
  ];
  List<Widget> tabs = [];

 final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
 
  Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    return (await showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return  CustomAppExitDialog(
                btnTxt1: AppStrings.yes,
                btnTxt2: AppStrings.no,
                title: AppStrings.exitDialogueTitle,     
                onTap1: (){
                  exit(0);
                },
                
              );
            })) ??
        false;
  }
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedIndex = widget.selectedIndex!;
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: AppColors.whiteColor,
        body: SafeArea(child:pages.elementAt(_selectedIndex)),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        floatingActionButton: _customFloatingActionButton(),
        bottomNavigationBar: _customBottomBar(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _customBottomBar() {
    return BottomAppBar(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        child: Padding(
          padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.sp, right: 15.sp,bottom: 10),
          child: Container(
              height:0.09.sh,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(
                      AssetPaths.navBarIcon,
                    ),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill),
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        _onItemTapped(0);
                      },
                      child: bottomBarItems(icon: AssetPaths.homeIcon,title: AppStrings.home)
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        _onItemTapped(1);
                      },
                      child: Padding(
                        padding:  EdgeInsets.only(right: 40.sp),
                        child: bottomBarItems(icon: AssetPaths.groupIcon,title: AppStrings.groups)
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        _onItemTapped(2);
                      },
                      child: Padding(
                      padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: 35.sp),
                        child: bottomBarItems(icon: AssetPaths.graph2Icon,title: AppStrings.appTitle)
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        _onItemTapped(3);
                      },
                      child: bottomBarItems(icon: AssetPaths.homeIcon,title: AppStrings.profile)
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
        ));
  }

  Widget _customFloatingActionButton() {
    return Visibility(
      visible: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom == 0.0,
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        child: Padding(
          padding:  EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 35.h,
          ),
          child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                // _onItemTapped(1);
                 CustomBottomModal().bottomModalSheet(
                    context: context,
                   
                    child:Column(
                      children: [
                        //create group
                        
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          // padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 16.0),
                          child: Row(
                            children:  [
                             const SizedBox(
                                width: 15.0,
                              ),
                             Image.asset(AssetPaths.groupIcon,color: AppColors.blueColor,scale: 3,),
                             const SizedBox(
                                width: 15.0,
                              ),
                              InkWell(
                                onTap: (){
                                  // CustomToast.showToast(message: AppStrings.postReportedSuccessfully);
                                  AppNavigation.navigatorPop(context);
                                  AppNavigation.navigateTo(context, AppRouteName.createGroupScreen,arguments: GroupArguments(isForGroupEdit: false,imagePath: null));
                                },
                                child: const CustomText(text: AppStrings.createGroup,fontColor: AppColors.blueColor,))
                              
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
    
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            AppNavigation.navigatorPop(context);
                            AppNavigation.navigateTo(context, AppRouteName.createbylstScreen,arguments: BylstArguments(isForbylstEdit: false));
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 16.0),
                            child: Row(
                              children:  [
                               const SizedBox(
                                  width: 15.0,
                                ),
                               Image.asset(AssetPaths.graph1Icon,color: AppColors.blueColor,scale: 3),
                               const SizedBox(
                                  width: 15.0,
                                ),
                                const CustomText(text: AppStrings.createbylst,fontColor: AppColors.blueColor,)
                                
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
              },
              child:CircleAvatar(
                radius: 50,
                child: Container(
                  height: 30,width: 30,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,color: AppColors.whiteColor),
                    child: const Icon(Icons.add,color: AppColors.blueColor,),),)
              // Image.asset(AssetPath.ADD_ICON2,scale: 3.5,)
              ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  bottomBarItems({String? title, String? icon}){
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            icon!,
            height: 20.h,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          10.height,
          CustomText(text: title,fontSize: 14,)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is home screen code

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _dobController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _searchUserController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _searchGroupController = TextEditingController();
  double searchLeftPadding=20.0,searchRightPadding=20.0;

 
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        appBar(context),
        Row(
          children: [
            searchTxtField(),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
               
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0.sp, right: 35.0.sp),
                child: Image.asset(AssetPaths.sliderIcon),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
         Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 50,
        shrinkWrap: true,
       physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            
            itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
           return Text("data");
         })),
        )
        // 30.height,
      ],
    );
  }

  appBar(context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.02, right: 0.02),
      child: CustomAppBar(
          leadingIconScale: 1,
          leadingIconPath: AssetPaths.drawerIcon,
          title: AppStrings.home,
          leadingIconColor: AppColors.blueColor,
          showBackButton: true,
          showAction: true,
          onTapLeading: () {
            ZoomDrawer.of(context)!.toggle();
          },
          actionWidget: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              AppNavigation.navigateTo(
                  context, AppRouteName.notificationScreenRoute);
            },
            child: Image.asset(
              AssetPaths.notificationIconForAppBar,
            ),
          )),
    );
  }

  searchTxtField() {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding:
            const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 0.0, top: 10, bottom: 10),
        child: CustomTextfield(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 20),
          hintText: AppStrings.searchHere,
          textColor: AppColors.blackColor,
          prefixIconPath: AssetPaths.searchIcon,
          prefixIconScale: 1.1,
          prefixIconColor: AppColors.blueColor,
          hintColor: AppColors.blueColor,
          bgColor: AppColors.lightBlueColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: there is no point in combining `SingleChildScrollView` with `ListView.builder` - what do you want to achieve with that?

Comment: @pskink if i remove SingleChildScrollView, i cant scroll and it is giving me ```A RenderFlex overflowed by 267 pixels on the bottom.``` on bottom.

Comment: remove `SingleChildScrollView` and wrap `ListView.builder` with `Expanded`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update answer:

SingleChildScrollView, ListView.build and the BottomNavigationBar were making the issue. remove the SingleChildScrollView wrapping the ListView with expanded and some change in BottomNavigationBar solves the issue.

Refer the below Code:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: _customBottomBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          // appBar(context),
          Row(
            children: [
              _searchTxtField(),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: const SizedBox.shrink(),
                // child: Image.asset(AssetPaths.sliderIcon),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 50,
                itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                  return const Text("data");
                })),
          )
          // 30.height,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _searchTxtField() {
    return const Expanded(
        child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 0.0, top: 10, bottom: 10),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 20),
          hintText: 'Search Here',
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }

  Widget _customBottomBar() {
    return BottomAppBar(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 20,
      child: SizedBox(
          height: 50,
          // decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          // image: DecorationImage(
          //     image: AssetImage(
          //       AssetPaths.navBarIcon,
          //     ),
          //     fit: BoxFit.fill),
          // ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              _bottomBarItems(icon: Icons.home, title: 'home'),
              _bottomBarItems(icon: Icons.group, title: 'groups'),
              _bottomBarItems(icon: Icons.title, title: 'appTitle'),
              _bottomBarItems(icon: Icons.person, title: 'profile'),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }

  Widget _bottomBarItems({icon, title}) {
    return Expanded(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Icon(
              icon,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            BaseText(
              title,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please change the widget and components you're using at your end, I have changed them so i can compile the code.

Comment: i tried this too, but still same issue. can i post the bottom navigation bar code?

Comment: yeah! add your whole code, it will be more helpful

Comment: `SingleChildScrollView`, 'ListView' and the BottomNavigationBar were making the issue, I'm updating my answer refer to that it will solve the problem.

Comment: you added Expanded in  _bottomBarItems is which is throwing ```Incorrect use of parent ``` widget error. and issue is still presist!

Comment: No improved it, so you no need to wrap the _buttonBarItems with `Inkwell` and `Expanded`, you just call the function and give parameter for assets and title and done it will do the job. For onTap functions of different items you can add a another parameter in the function as onTap and handle that in the function call.

Comment: actually, i use code as it and check its output it is working but if i use the same on my code issue is still presist.

Comment: put your whole code for this page and i'll try to solve it.

Comment: Hey pixel, i solved the issue, i got the exact widget where issue is coming from! thanks for your time, i accpeted your answer too! have a nice day!